# Understanding why $\int_\gamma {dz \over z - a} = k 2\pi i$ for $\gamma$ a closed curve not passing through $a$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

The following is a paraphrased proof from Ahlfors.  I bolded the part that is confusing me and asked a question about it at the bottom of this post.

**Hypothesis:** Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve that does not pass through $a$.

${}$

**Proof:**

1. Let the equation of $\gamma$ be $\gamma(t)$ for
   $\alpha \le t \le \beta$.
2. Define $h(t)$ as follows:

   $$h(t) = \int_a^t {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t) - a}\ dt$$
3. Then we have that

   $$h'(t) = {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t) - a}$$

   by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
4. **From this equation it follows that the derivative of
   $e^{-h(t)} (\gamma(t) - a)$ vanishes except perhaps at a finite
   number of points, and since this function is continuous it must
   reduce to a constant. (Why is this?)**
5. We thus have

   $$e^{h(t)} = {\gamma(t) - a \over \gamma(\alpha) - a}$$
6. Since $\gamma(\beta) = \gamma(\alpha)$ we obtain $e^{h(\beta)} = 1$,
   and therefore $h(\beta)$ must be a multiple of $2 \pi i$. This
   completes the proof.

**Question:** How is the computation in (4) working?  Are there known rules for computing exponential functions with integrals as their inputs?  I don't understand how the computation in (5) is working either, but I assume once I understand (4) that will take care of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the computation in part (4), just treat $h(t)$ as some black boxed function. So, using the chain rule and product rule, since $\gamma(t) \not= a$ for any $t$,

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{-h(t)}(\gamma(t) - a) = -e^{-h(t)}h'(t)(\gamma(t) - a) + e^{-h(t)}(\gamma'(t)) = e^{-h(t)}\left(\gamma'(t) - \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t) - a}(\gamma(t) - a)\right) = 0.$$

To show that Step 5 follows from Step 4, we note that if the complex derivative of a function is $0$ at all but finitely many points, then the function must be constant. So, for some complex number $c$, we have

$$c = e^{-h(t)}(\gamma(t) - a) \Rightarrow e^{h(t)} = \frac{\gamma(t) - a}{c}.$$

Now, plugging in $t = \alpha$, give us $h(\alpha) = 0$ (by the way, your lower bound for the integral in part (2) is $\alpha$ not $a$.) Hence, we have

$$c = e^{-0}(\gamma(\alpha) - a) = (\gamma(\alpha) - a).$$

Thus, we have

$$e^{h(t)} = \frac{\gamma(t) - a}{\gamma(\alpha) - a}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I fail to see, however, how the bottom equality arises (with the $e^{-h(t)}$ factored out).  It seems to the me the expression on the top right reduces to $e^{-h(t)} \left(-h'(t) \gamma(t) + h'(t) a + \gamma'(t)  \right)$, which is not obviously equal zero.  Are you making any substitutions in this equation?

Comment: Yes. I made one substitution: $h'(t) = \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t) - a}.$ Also, I didn't separate the $\gamma(t) - a$ as it cancels the denominator of the $h'(t)$.

Comment: OK -- I completely understand step (4) now.  Do you know how (5) follows from (4)?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I wish m.se would let me give you an extra bounty for this answer.  This was an extremely clear answer that saved me a lot of headache.  Thanks for your help.